# TypeError: str.replace is not a function (Angular 2 Universal)

Tags: angular, angular2-universal

I am using [Angular 2 Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal).

I have this line in the html part:

```
<span [hidden]="!error">{{error}}</span>
```

It works perfect on the client side, but is shows this error in the **terminal** (because of server rendering) when the page loads:

> Rendering Document Error: TypeError: str.replace is not a function

Comment: Do you mean `[class.hidden]`?

Comment: I was making the assumption that you had defined a class `.hidden { display: none; }`.

Comment: @torazaburo sorry to make you misunderstand, no I don't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One walkaround solution is using `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]`:

```
<span *ngIf="!!error">{{error}}</span>
```

This can get rid of

> Rendering Document Error: TypeError: str.replace is not a function

when server renders.

---

BTW, I would be glad to accept another answer if anyone can find a way using `[hidden]` without error.